# Changing the input after focus is removed from directive in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I just want to change my input after the focus is removed from particular element (using directive only) I dont want to use `ng-focus` and `ng-blur`
For eg - Here i want to change my text to uppercase when the focus is lost from 
textbox
I have one textbox

```
<input type = "text" ng-model = "text" upper>
```

Here upper is my directive

```
app.directive('upper', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            function fromUser(text) {
                alert(text);
                var  transFormetInput = text;
                transFormetInput = transFormetInput.toUpperCase();
                 alert(transFormetInput);
                return transFormetInput;
            }
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
        }
    };
});
```

Now here my $parser will change my output on every word enter in model
ie on every letter it will get fire I want to change the model after my scope has changed.

Here is my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZQyLf0cTAaHb1WKuYWZj?p=preview)

This plunker has two issues.

1)As i have used $parser here it is firing on every word enter which i dont want,i want it to fire when my focus is lost from my textbox.

2) my model is not changing from my directive.

Comment: if you need this only for the visual effect, you could simply use css, e.g. .my-element: { text-transform: uppercase; }; .my-element:focus { text-transform: initial; }

Comment: No i dont want only visual,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to save your plunker but I do not have permissions, so, just use like this.

```
app.directive('upper', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      element.on('blur', function() {
        element[0].value = element[0].value.toUpperCase();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

here the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/jMo9VCThgjrVVu5CY1sp?p=preview

Comment: Thanku that helped but is it safe to use $apply(); ?

Comment: Actually you don't need it in this case. Just remove it. I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want the blur, try something like this:

```
link: (scope, el, attr, ctrl) => {
  el.bind('blur', () => {
    el.val(ctrl.yourInput.value);
  });
}
```

Your value that you want should be on the controller/model (4th arg in link). I'd suggest assigning it to a variable everytime it is updated, which you can then access in the el.bind('blur') method.

Comment: My value is not updating can you please add a  plunker using my plunker and make it work??